# How to reset local default administrator password in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I forgot my default local administrator password for windows 10. Kindly help me to reset or bypass password login screen in simple steps.

Comment: Log in with another administrator account and reset it.

Comment: I do not have other administrator account, else would have reset using the same. Please help me to create other account with full rights so that I can reset the default administrator password

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you followed any of the countless guides on how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

1-if you want to access your files you can boot from a Linux live CD.

2-if you want to reset the password there is some tools to do so e.g : Kon-boot